# Bold keyword in listing, but deletekeywords does not seem to work

Tags: listings, keywords, sql

I'm using the lstlisting package to write down the SQL queries. However, the word **character** appear in bold, because it is considered a keyword. I added it to the list of keyword to remove `deletekeywords`, but it does not seem to work. Although, if I put WHERE in the list of the `deletekeywords` list, it does work, unbolding it.

move it from the list o keywords.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp} % listings straight quote
\begin{document}
    \lstset{
        language=SQL,tabsize=2,upquote=true,
        %keywordstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries,basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        moredelim=[is][\underbar]{__}{__},
        morekeywords={ilike},
        sensitive=false,
        deletekeywords = {CHARACTER,character,WHERE},
    }
  \begin{lstlisting}
  SELECT m.title,c.id,p.name,ch.name
  FROM movie m
  JOIN casting c ON m.id = c.movie_id
  JOIN person p ON p.id=c.person_id
  JOIN character ch ON ch.id=c.char_id
  WHERE m.title ILIKE '%legend%';
  \end{lstlisting} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of lstlisting that do not delete keyword]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: @BambOo I've just updated the question.

Comment: Is my answer conform with your request ?

Comment: Thank you so much,  @BambOo. Your answer worked like a charm. If you could also vote my question, I'll would appreciate too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `listings` manual, the passing arguments to the `deletekeywords` option should look like `deletekeywords=[<number>]{<list of keywords>}`. I did not find the correct `<number>` in the documentation, but playing a bit with values shows that `<number>=2` works in your case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp} % listings straight quote
\begin{document}
    \lstset{
        language=SQL,tabsize=2,upquote=true,
        %keywordstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries,basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        moredelim=[is][\underbar]{__}{__},
        morekeywords={ilike},
        sensitive=false,
        deletekeywords =[2]{CHARACTER,character,WHERE},
    }
  \begin{lstlisting}
  SELECT m.title,c.id,p.name,ch.name
  FROM movie m
  JOIN casting c ON m.id = c.movie_id
  JOIN person p ON p.id=c.person_id
  JOIN character ch ON ch.id=c.char_id
  WHERE m.title ILIKE '%legend%';
  \end{lstlisting} 
\end{document}
```

[image]